# Rails Query with ILIKE

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, parameters, find

I have written a finder as follows:

```
@cars = @cars.joins(:manufacturers).where("manufacturers.name ILIKE ?", params[:manufacturer].gsub!(/-/, ' '))
```

`params[:manufacturer]` comes through in a form of a string that has been `.parameterize`d by Rails.

The problem is that a string with an "'" or an "&" in it doesn't get matched by ILIKE correctly.

So as an example, some strings that are stored in my DB and their parameterized versions:

1. "This is a test" parameterized: "this-is-a-test" gsubbed: "this is a test"
2. "He didn't do it" parameterized: "he didn-t-do-it" gsubbed: "he didn t do it"
3. "This & That" parameterized: "this-that" gsubbed: "this that"

So when I do ILIKE between the first part of 2 and the third part of 2, it does not create a match. Same with 3. 1 obviously works fine though.

Any ideas how to get a correct match even with special characters in the strings?

Comment: what db you are using ?

Comment: Curious, is it necessary to accept the search params from the url? I had a similar issue i solved it by accepting the search params via post request. Then the search term and its corresponding url would be stored in a search table, as such urls are necessary for SEO. So later on when someone visit that url, it loads the term from the db and do the search.

Comment: Is this like a slug or something ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady  Good point. That would make it all super easy. I should add a slug to my table and then can query based on that. Thanks!

Comment: @Coderhs The whole page is built using filters and sorts based on query string parameters. I could change it so it works like that but currently query strings are how it's working.

Comment: lol no problem, guess I'll add an answer

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes, go for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a lot similar to a slug system, you should just add a new field and call it whatever you find suitable, just don't forget to add an `index` so you don't waste time searching in strings.

Also you could add a `before_create` or `before_save` callback to auto create it when you save the object, in the format you are planning to search for.

Comment: Went this way in the end. Added a slug to my model. Passed the slug through the query string and then found the model instance by comparing parameter slug to model DB slug. Works perfectly. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 24):

This is the way to do it:

```
@cars = @cars.joins(:manufacturers).where("manufacturers.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:manufacturer].parameterize}%")
```

By the way, you can do this, it looks cleaner:

```
search = params[:manufacturer].parameterize
@cars = @cars.joins(:manufacturers).where("manufacturers.name LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: Just tried that and still no matches when a "'" or "&" is in the string.

Comment: I think removing the bang(!) will solve your problem :)

Comment: Sorry, but still nothing

Comment: BTW, What do the %# do?

Comment: % will ignore the words before and after of that word and #{} for ruby string manipulation.

Comment: @rctneil, I have updated my answer, can you check it?

Comment: %  is SQL that says  "anything", similar to "*" in other contexts

Answer (score 2):

Use the [sanitize_sql_like](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_like) method to correctly escape the special characters.